# 403 Forbidden - PortalSiteMapProvider was unable to fetch current node

Tags: 403, portalsitemapprovider

We have two development machines and we have a web application in the same port in both machines. We are using FBA and Windows authentication in our application with a custom login page located in "~/_layouts/Pages/Login.aspx", both machines have the same custom login page. The page is made in VS and is deployed with another features.

But here's the deal, in one of the machines the browser gets a **403 Forbidden** when it tries to open the page, in the other machine it works alright and we can log both with FBA and Windows.

We have checked all the permissions for the Network Service (App Pool account) and it has the same permissions in both machines, for both "Policy for Web Application" and Content DB (db_owner). We have checked the web.config files for CA, STS and Site and they are identical in both machines. And if we change to the default login page, it works alright.

So we have no clue why it works in one machine and it doesn't work in the other.

Inspecting the Log File it shows the following error:

> PortalSiteMapProvider was unable to fetch current node, request URL:
>   /_layouts/Pages/Login.aspx, message: Access is denied. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)), stack trace:    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.HandleAccessDenied(Exception
>   ex)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.OpenWeb(String
>   bstrUrl, String& pbstrServerRelativeUrl, String& pbstrTitle, String&
>   pbstrDescription, String& pbstrTitleResourceId, String&
>   pbstrDescriptionResourceId, Guid& pguidID, String&
>   pbstrRequestAccessEmail, UInt32& pwebVersion, Guid& pguidScopeId,
>   UInt32& pnAuthorID, UInt32& pnLanguage, UInt32& pnLocale, UInt16&
>   pnTimeZone, Boolean& bTime24, Int16& pnCollation, UInt32&
>   pnCollationLCID, Int16& pnCalendarType, Int16& pnAdjustHijriDays,
>   Int16& pnAltCalendarType, Boolean& pbShowWeeks, Int16&
>   pnFirstWeekOfYear, UInt32& pnFirstDayOfWeek, Int16& pnWorkDays, Int16&
>   pnWorkDayStartHour, Int16& pnWorkDayEndHour, Int16& pnMeetingCount,
>   Int32& plFlags, Boolean& bConnectedToPortal, String& pbstrPortalUrl,
>   String& pbstrPortalName, Int32& plWebTemplateId, Int16&
>   pnProvisionConfig, String& pbstrDefaultTheme, String&
>   pbstrDefaultThemeCSSUrl, String& pbstrThemedCssFolderUrl, String&
>   pbstrAlternateCSSUrl, String& pbstrCustomizedCssFileList, String&
>   pbstrCustomJSUrl, String& pbstrAlternateHeaderUrl, String&
>   pbstrMasterUrl, String& pbstrCustomMasterUrl, String&
>   pbstrSiteLogoUrl, String& pbstrSiteLogoDescription, Object& pvarUser,
>   Boolean& pvarIsAuditor, UInt64& ppermMask, Boolean& bUserIsSiteAdmin,
>   Boolean& bHasUniquePerm, Guid& pguidUserInfoListID, Guid&
>   pguidUniqueNavParent, Int32& plSiteFlags, DateTime&
>   pdtLastContentChange, DateTime& pdtLastSecurityChange, String&
>   pbstrWelcomePage, Boolean& pbOverwriteMUICultures, Boolean&
>   pbMUIEnabled, String& pbstrAlternateMUICultures, Int32& puiVersion,
>   Int16& pnClientTag)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.InitWeb()     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.get_TitleResource()     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.CachedArea.CreateCachedArea(PublishingWeb
>   area, CachedObjectFactory factory, String parentId)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.CachedObjectFactory.CreateObject(PublishingWeb
>   area, String parentUrl)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Navigation.PortalSiteMapProvider.get_CurrentNode()

Can someone help us?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you using the same account to login?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a custom masterpage in which you have inserted a SiteMapPath control, this control will fail as files located in the `/_layouts/` folder is not a part of SharePoint, thus the SiteMapPath cannot index it and therefor it fails to find a matching item in it's data source causing it to throw this error.